# Getting current working directory rather than filename directory, using Path.GetFullPath

Tags: vb.net, path, filenames

Running windows 10 and visual basic.net (vs 2015)

With this piece of code:

```
substr6 = Path.GetFullPath(filename.txt)
```

I'm getting the current working directory rather than the filename one.
My current working dir is "my documentes\vs2015\projects\namelist\"
Filename sit in; "C:\program files\new projects\List1\filename.txt"
As you can see nothing to do, so how can I get the correct filename full path?

With this one I'm getting the same but as the opposite with the previews one, I'm getting current dir + filename as well.

```
Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(substr5)
Dim folderPath As String = testFile.DirectoryName
Dim fileName As String = testFile.Name
```

I guess it has something to do with relative/absolute paths, or maybe I'm wrong, I'm a beginner.
Similar question does not fit my issue or they doesn't using visual basic.net, can someone help me please?

Comment: If you already selected the file, you get full path from it with .FullName. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_FileSystemInfo_FullName

Comment: I'll give a go as soon as possible, I ran now into another issue "PathTooLong" I'm going to migrate project to framework 4.71 to skip that issue.Maybe  I'll has to rewrite some piece of code because this, who knows? next weekend I'll know the answers. :)